# Can I safely use this weak self auto type shortcut ?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

Is this safe to do ?

```
#define wvar __weak __auto_type
```

and then usage

```
wvar _self = self;
_filterMenuItem = [self addMenuItem:@"Filter" :^{
    [_self.filterWithHeader toggleVisible];
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Safe**.  The critical part is that the variable is declared `__weak`.  So long as you then use it as an instance of `self` -- and not some other class -- the runtime doesn't care what type the compiler thought it was (and in this case, the compiler will know that `__auto_type` *is* the right type).

Remember also that the weak qualifier is only required if `self` directly or indirectly retains the block in which it is referenced.  For many blocks, plain old `self` is safe from retain cycles.

Comment: Yes man I already discovered that it is not always required but its just not so easy visible if required or if not. Compiler is giving me warnings but i am not sure if thats 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You don't store any reference into wvar. This is just a convenient way to save some time if you type "__weak __auto_type" a lot :)

Comment: Yes and its also much nicer 
wvar _self = self;
vs
__weak __auto_type _self = self;
Sure i do it a lot... I use blocks a lot.